# Why was the concept of velocity created?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, speed

Why do we use velocity instead of speed for different physics problems?
I recognize how they are different but why use one over the other?

Comment: The speed alone does not fully describe your motion. You also need direction. Velocity includes both speed and direction, so it describes the motion. Sometimes that is relevant, other times not

Comment: It's because of how the universe works. Physicists use (and sometimes invent) mathematics to describe how the universe works. Some of our oldest physical laws describe relationships between velocity, mass, momentum, energy, etc. You're welcome to try to invent your own laws in which the speed of a particle matters but the direction of its motion doesn't; but good luck getting your direction-free laws to say anything interesting about how the universe actually works. If you ever succeed, then I'll wager that you've actually just re-invented vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do we use velocity instead of speed for different physics
>   problems? I recognize how they are different but why use one over the
>   other?

My cottage is 100 km due north of my house in Toronto.

If I drive 100 km/h, will I arrive at my cottage in an hour?

What if I drive east?

What if I start in Montreal?

Thus **velocity**.

Answer (score 1):

Circular motion at constant speed had varying velocity because of the constantly changing direction of motion. This made possible the evaluation of centripetal force causing the rotation which depended on the rate of change of velocity( direction was changing) not speed. Had it not been so we would not have been able to determine the force(cause) behind uniform circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a Vector Quantity, it tells us magnitude as well as direction. But speed is a scalar quantity so it only tells us magnitude . In most cases, physics deals with things moving in a certain direction. So, we need a uniform system to define how fast an object is moving, in what direction it is moving, where will it be in the next $~t~$ seconds, etc.etc. So, it's more convenient to use velocity instead of speed.